# context menu in android 7.0

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-7.0-nougat, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm struggling with the following situation:

I create the context menus in ListViews by overriding the onCreateContextMenu
method from the listview

```
        myListView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new View.OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

            AdapterContextMenuInfo ctxmenu = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;

            int pos = ctxmenu.position;
            mLastEmpresaSelected = m_empresas.get(pos);


            menu.setHeaderTitle("Title Header");
            menu.add(Menu.NONE,myItem1, 1, "Item 1");
            menu.add(Menu.NONE,myItem1, 2, "Item 2");





        }
    });
```

Now this works fine in previous Android versions, but in Android 7 i get a small menu at the bottom of the screen which must be scrolled.

This is not very practical, so I'm trying to make a context menu like the ones I was used to.

I'm currently using api level 10 (Android 2.3.3 - Gingerbread)

I've seen a workaround  in this place:

https://www.mysysadmintips.com/other/programming/758-listview-pop-up-context-menu-broken-in-android-7-api-24

but then i get these warnings:

error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu'

error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:contextPopupMenuStyle'

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.

I understand that in api level 10 the theme does not exist. I'm trying to find a workarround without changing the target API.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am also facing same issue. any solutions??